# Union in Spring JPA Or Specification

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, jpa-criteria

Trying to create criteria builder for below query. However seems UNION is not supported by JPA. Any thoughts ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   firsttable i1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   secondtable 
               WHERE  id = i1.fid 
                      AND flag = 'Flag1') 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   secondtable 
               WHERE  id = i1.fid 
                      AND flag = 'Flag2') 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM   firsttable i1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   secondtable 
               WHERE  id = i1.fid 
                      AND flag = 'Flag1') 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   secondtable 
               WHERE  id = i1.fid 
                      AND flag = 'Flag2');
```

Comment: There are multiple approaches to imitate the `UNION`. Run 2 separate queries and merge results, create a VIEW on DB side and use it for retrieving, combine the query condition to be `condition 1 OR condition2`

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking about VIEW approach, However I really need to do this task for an urgent delivery and I  was thinking if there is a way in JPA or Criteria to acccomplish it in someway.